# $AAAPPPLMNOOXQSDF$ number of anagrams such that there aren't three consecutives letters that are the same

Tags: combinatorics

$AAAPPPLMNOOXQSDF$

I would like to calculate thenumber of anagrams such that there aren't three consecutives that are the same. 
Yet I don't really know how to proceed any ideas ?

Comment: Can you compute the total number of anagrams?  Now consider the A's as a block and compute the number.  Subtract these.  Also subtract the number with the P's as a block.  The ones with both the A's and P's as a block....

Comment: ...and add that last number !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find that there are $\frac{16!}{3!3!2!}$ anagrams, then subtract those having consecutive $A$'s. You can calculate their number pretending that the three $A$'s are a single letter. So $-\frac{14!}{3!2!}$. Do this again for the $P$'s. But this way you have subtracted twice the anagrams having both $A$'s and $P$'s grouped, that have to be added in back: $+\frac{12!}{2!}$. All in all:
$$\frac{16!}{3!3!2!}-2\times\frac{14!}{3!2!}+\frac{12!}{2!}$$

Comment: Thank you, great explanation !

Answer (score 1):

Since there's only two letters that are repeated $3$ times one can use the inlcusion/exclusion principle without too much hassle:

There's $\dfrac{16!}{3!3!2!}$ total anagrams, out of those $\dfrac{14!}{3!2!}$ contain the block $AAA$ and $\dfrac{14!}{3!2!}$ contain the block $PPP$, but we've double counted some, since $\dfrac{12!}{3!2!}$ contain both blocks.

The total amount is thus:

$$\dfrac{16!}{3!2!} - 2\dfrac{14!}{3!2!} + \dfrac{12!}{3!2!}$$

Comment: Great explanation !